# Prove that the subgroup of the quotient group is cycling and infinitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, cyclic-groups

$$M = \left\{\,\dfrac{m}{13^n}\biggm| m\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in\mathbb{N} \,\right\}, \quad G = M/\mathbb{Z}$$

Prove that any subgroup $H < G$, $H\neq G$ is cyclic and infinitely generated and that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G$.

I can't find a generator for $H$; if you could give me some ideas, I would really appreciate.

What I have tried so far: factoring the group : factoring: $G=\{1^*,1/13^*,{1/13^2}^*,{1/13^3}^*,\ldots\}$ where $^*$ stands for class.

Comment: Be sure to include what you tried so far!

Comment: @TimBurton For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: This is very similar to a question that was closed one hour ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627377/i-need-help-with-this-problem)!?

Comment: "cyclic and inifinitely generated"??

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) 
$$H\subsetneqq G\implies \frac1{13^n}+\Bbb Z\notin H\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;n\in\Bbb N$$

Let $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ be the minimal such power, meaning $\;\frac1{13^k}+\Bbb Z\in H\;\;\forall\,k<n\;$ . Show now that

$$H=\left\langle \;\frac1{13^{n-1}}+\Bbb Z\;\right\rangle\cong C_{13^{n-1}}$$

(2) Any finite number of elements from $\;M/\Bbb Z$ involves only a finite number of powers of $\;13\;$ in the denominators...

(3) If $\;H\;$ has the form described above, define

$$\phi:G\to G\;,\;\;\phi(\alpha):=13^{n-1}\alpha\;,\;\;\alpha\in G=M/\Bbb Z$$

and now show what has to be shown and apply the FIT(=First Isomorphism Theorem)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have just one question. What is C?

Comment: That what happens to hints: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153646/how-to-prove-the-cyclicity-of-the-subgroup-defined-as-such

Answer (score 0):

For $g\in G$, let $f(g)=\min\{\,n\in\mathbb N_0\mid \exists m\colon \frac m{13 }\in g\,\}$. Show that $$\tag 1g\in\langle h\rangle \iff f(g)\le f(h).$$
Thus if $f$ is unbounded on $H$ then $H=G$. So for a proper subgroup $H$ we find $h\in H$ that maximizes $f$ and hence is a generator of $H$.
Oberve that we may choose the generator $h$ in the form $\frac1{13^n}+\mathbb Z$.
Conclude that multiplicaton with $13^n$ is an isomorphism $G\to G/H$.

Generalizing $(1)$, show that 
$$ g\in \langle h_1, \ldots, h_k\rangle\implies f(g)\le\max\{f(h_1),\ldots,f(h_k)\}$$
and conclude that $G$ is not finitely generated because $f$ is unbounded on $G$.

Comment: Thanks you very much for editing and for your answer.